# Overlapping div's when using textarea on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, layout, overflow

In the images below I believe the problem to be self explanatory. The content works perfectly up until trying to enter text. Any advice on what is causing this would be appreciated. Sorry the images are so large. I have removed some HTML (the logo, menu and hidden navbar) for easier reading

[image]

[image]

```
 <section class="contact-background" id="particles-js" >
</section>
    <section class="contact-page">
<div class="contact-container">
    <h1>Get In Touch</h1>
        <div class="border"></div>
    <p>I'll get back to you promptly</p>
    <form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="POST">

        <input class="contact-form-text" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full name" tabindex="1" required>
        <input  class="contact-form-text" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" tabindex="2" required>
        <input class="contact-form-text" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3" required>
        <textarea class="contact-form-text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" tabindex="4"></textarea>
        <button class="contact-form-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Send</button>

    </form>
</div>
</section>
```

```
    body{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;;
}
```

```
#particles-js{
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```
 .contact-page{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
 .contact-container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```
.contact-form{
    display: flex;
    max-width: 60rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has something to so with your use of `position: absolute;`. Why are you using it on most of your container elements?

Comment: I figured that might be the case but if that is the real issue, I do not know. I’m using absolute because of the js-particle layer. You could view the website here, its only up and running for development at the moment and you cannot see this bug without using a phone

http://127.0.0.1:3000/contact.html

Comment: @DecisiveDevelopment unfortunately you have set your development environment up on a local server. I can't view your local server. You could put your code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share the link here. That way its easier for me to view.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link. http://www.decisive-development.com/contact.html

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see here is with contact-container css, you are giving height to 100% and content to be center. So when your keyboard is on your viewport becomes small and all content including form and h1 are trying to stay center.

Your contact-container is position absolute so it will be absolute to HTML tag and while form will try to be relative to HTML as instead of contact-container contain.

Try changing contact-container position to relative.

Comment: That does make sense. Would I need to add a position to the parent of contact-container (contact-page) also?

Comment: I have added the position and the bug is still occuring.

Comment: Perhaps adding min-height properties somewhere could work around this?

Comment: First thing change your .logo-container position to relative so your form doesn't overlap your absolute content.

Alternatively  you can add same amount of padding to .contact-container.

Comment: #particles-js {
min-height: 80rem;
}
.contact-page {
min-height: 80rem;

This has fixed the issue but It would not have worked without changing some absolutes to relative. Thanks for your help